# use touchdb in titanium for android application

Tags: android, titanium, touchdb

I have to use touchdb in titanium  for an android application and I don't understand what plugin I have to use and how configure and use it.. somebody can help me??

Answer (score 0):

i think you're a bit confused.

First of all plugins are the way PhoneGap calls its extensions, are you using PhoneGap/Cordova or Titanium?

In the second case you're in need of a native module.
There seem to be a sleeping project for both platform maybe you could get some inspiration from [it](https://github.com/pegli/couchdb_client).

EC:
here is a "more or less" active TouchDB module for both platforms [TiTouchDB](https://github.com/pegli/ti_touchdb)!!! Enjoy.